# PhoneGap: download & save binary files (mp3s) for iPhone & Android

Tags: iphone, android, file, html, cordova

Is there a way in PhoneGap to download & save a binary file (I'm specifically interested in mp3s) that works across both iPhone and Android?

A web search reveals a plugin for Android:
http://www.toforge.com/2011/02/phonegap-android-plugin-for-download-files-from-url-on-sd-card/
And some code for iPhone:
http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/1097750723/phonegap-plugin-for-downloading-url
But nothing that covers both.

Comment: Update: My colleague Joe Halliwell has written and tested an Android/iPhone solution for this. He'll probably share details if asked nicely. See http://www.winterwell.com/company/people.php for Joe's contact details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhoneGap has evolved & added this functionality.

Comment: I assume you're referring to the File API: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File

Comment: Yes - specifically FileTransfer

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you write some lines of javascript code to hide them both behind the same interface (you will have to provide different storage locations anyway)

Their interfaces look pretty similar already

Comment: it's already done. have a look at http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/de.fastr.phonegap.plugins.downloader